# ImageButton LayoutProblem with setImageDrawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-image

I'm trying to set an image of an ImageButton at runtime. It should fill the width of the screen and use as much space in height as it needs to scale correctly.

The ImageButton is declared as followed:

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/map_plan_topview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:onClick="onMapImageClicked"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Now I'm trying to set the image with:

```
        ImageButton topView = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.map_plan_topview);
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(path);
        topView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

The Images width is scaled with fill_parent, but is not correctly stretched in height.
If I use 
`topView.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_where_citymap);` instead, everything works fine, but I do want to set the source from a filepath at runtime.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`fitXY` stretches the image without respecting proportions. If proportions matter, then use `center_crop`, or `center_inside`

You can set the `ScaleType` in code as well:

```
ImageButton topView = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.map_plan_topview);
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(path);
topView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
topView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Comment: I thought adjustViewBounds keeps the aspectRatio of the the image. However, when I tried it with CENTER_CROP and CENTER_INSIDE it both works when using setImageRessource but it does not do the same when I use setImageDrawable. CENTER_CROP doesn't show me the whole image (although it is rightly scaled) and CENTER_INSIDE shows me the whole image, but doesn't fill the parents width.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "`SetImageResource`" in place of "`setImage Drawable`"...!